# Jquery mobile + Php authentication system

Tags: jquery, session, mobile

I'm writing an authentication system with mobile jquery and php. The html code is as follows:

```
    <div data-role = "page" id ="dialogo">
        <a href = "#identificacion" id = "formdialog" data-rel="dialog"> </a>
    </div>
    
     <div data-role = "page" id = "identificacion">
        <div id ="main"> 
            <div id ="caplogin">
                <img src = "images/vives_logo.png"/>
                <p> Acceso</p>
                <div style ="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style ="clear:both;"></div>
            <div id ="formlogin">
            <form name ="formautentificacion" id ="formautentificacion" method = "post" action = "" data-ajax="false">
                <table>
                    <tr> <td> Login </td> <td> <input type ="text" name ="user" id ="user" size="30"/></td> </tr>
                    <tr> <td> Password </td><td><input type ="password" name ="pass" id="pass" size="30"/></td></tr>
                    <tr> <td colspan = "2" align ="right"> <input type = "submit" id = "sbmt_aut" name = "sbmt_aut" value = "ENTRAR"/></td>
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role = "page" id = "pageclients">
      
        <div id = "headerpageclient">
            <a href="index.php" class ="logout" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">SALIR</a> 
        </div>
        <div id = "clientes">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role = "page" id = "pagepuntosventa">
        <div id = "headerpagepuntoventa">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have two ajax function to start and destroy php sessions, and use changepage it according with ajax response, for login the the functionality is correct and logout, but the safari back button doesn't working and falls on the last page.

```
 $(document).delegate("#dialogo", "pageinit", function() {
    $("#formdialog").click();
})


    $(document).delegate("#identificacion", "pageinit", function() {
    
    
    $("#formautentificacion").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ax/login.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data == 1)
                {
                    //$.mobile.changePage("promocion.php", {transition: "flip"});
                    //window.location = "index.php";
                    $.mobile.changePage("#pageclients", {transition: "flip"});
                }
                else
                {
                    if (data == 2)
                        alert("Usuario bloqueado, 3 intentos fallidos");
                    else
                        alert("Error en la identificación");
                }
                
                $("#user").val("");
                $("#pass").val("");
            }
        })
    })
    
    $(".logout").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        logout();
    })
})

$(document).delegate("#pageclients", "pageinit", function() {
    seguridad();
})
```

Function seguridad() for check that session is on:

```
session_start();

include("../class/aut.php");
$aut = new aut();

$res = 0;

if (!empty($_SESSION["usuario"]) && !empty($_SESSION["token"]) )
{
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["usuario"]);
    $_SESSION["token"] = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["token"]);
    
    if ( $aut->checktoken($_SESSION["usuario"],$_SESSION["token"]) )
    {
        $_SESSION["token"] = md5(rand().$_SESSION["usuario"]);
        $aut->updateToken($_SESSION["usuario"], $_SESSION["token"]);
        $res = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        session_destroy();
        session_unset();
        $res = 0;
        //header("Location: index.php");
        //exit;
    }
}
else
{
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    $res = 0;
    //header("Location: index.php");
    //exit;
}

echo $res;
?>
```

And function logout:

```
function logout()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ax/logout.php',
        cache:false,
        //async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#formdialog").click();
        }
    })
}
```

I try to close the session and then on each page with the security function to verify the session. But once destroyed the session I can go back to a page and not skip dialogue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button to exit the application I've made ​​as follows:

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Js

```
function logout()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ax/logout.php',
        cache:false,
        //async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log("LOGOUT");
            //$.mobile.changePage("#dialogo");
        }

    })
    $.mobile.changePage("http://10.0.74.199/representantes");
}
```

And the link to logout

```
<a href="index.php" class ="logout ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-theme="a">Salir</a>
```

And html for the fisrt page:

```
<div data-role = "page" id ="dialogo">
            <a href = "#identificacion" id = "formdialog" data-rel="dialog"> </a>
        </div>

         <div data-role = "page" id = "identificacion" data-overlay-theme="f">
            <div id ="main"> 
                <div id ="caplogin">
                    <img src = "http://10.0.74.199/representantes/images/vives_logo.png"/>
                    <p> Acceso Promoción Vives </p>
                    <div style ="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style ="clear:both;"></div>
                <div id ="formlogin">
                <form name ="formautentificacion" id ="formautentificacion" method = "post" action = ""  data-ajax="false">
                    <table>
                        <tr> <td> Login </td> <td> <input type ="text" name ="user" id ="user" size="30"/></td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td> Password </td><td><input type ="password" name ="pass" id="pass" size="30"/></td></tr>
                        <tr> <td colspan = "2" align ="right"> <input type = "submit" id = "sbmt_aut" name = "sbmt_aut" value = "ENTRAR"/></td>
                    </table>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And when the first pageinit, force click

```
$(document).delegate("#dialogo", "pageinit", function() {
    $("#formdialog").click();
})
```

With this if you close the application, but this fails when I click back button history, index.php not redirect to initial dialeg.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that jQueryMobile keeps a cache of the previously visited pages in the DOM. You should try removing all the pages (or at least the first page) so that when the user revisits it jQueryMobile will refetch its contents and trigger your session code.

```
$('#somepage').remove();
```

Comment: $.mobile.changePage doesn't work into success ajax function, if the html file is multipage, how can i use remove() method with the pages, the first page #dialogo, i shouldn't remove because is the first page.
Now, I do not know why when pressing the back button executes a get ajax with the URL index.php (this is run jquery get and do not know why). 
With all this, the function is correct